# Hyperlinked Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, doi

I am using RSC reference style for the bibliography of my master thesis. I want to hyperlink each of my bibliography item with its doi so that if I click on a reference then it should direct me to its external doi link. But I dont want to show the doi of the references.

I am using `natbib` package and my bibliography file is `.bib` file. I am using TeXmaker. I am very new to LateX and as a result of some research on the internet, I know I have to modify the `rsc.bst` file. I tried but there is no change in the bibliography. I would be thankful if someone help me in this matter. You can download the `rsc.bst` and `.bib` files from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfr6ztozxhii3lm/rsc%20and%20bib%20files.rar?dl=0).

Following is the minimal working example of the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   urlcolor=blue,    % color of external links
   linkcolor=black,  % color of toc, list of figs etc.
   citecolor=blue,   % color of links to bibliography
}
\begin{document}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{bibliography}   % bibliography in table of contents

This is rsc \cite{RN8423} reference style \cite{RN8437}.

\bibliographystyle{rsc}
\bibliography{thesis_bib}

\end{document}
```

Added comment:

Actually, I am using `rsc` style because of my references, there are many chemical formulae or names in the titles. So I don't want to spend much time correcting them by subscripting or supercripting the texts. I am willing to use any other style in which title field is hidden. Also, I am willing to switch to `biblatex` ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you so much @samcarter and @Kurt. I have edited my post and added link to download the `rsc.bst` and `.bib` files. Also, I have added the minimal working example with bibliography.

Comment: If you are willing to switch to `biblatex`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn

Comment: Actually, I am using `rsc` style because of my references, there are many chemical formulae or names in the titles. So I don't want to spend much time correcting them by subscripting or supercripting the texts. I am willing to use any other style in which title field is hidden. Also, I am willing to switch to `biblatex`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you mentioned that you are willing to change to `biblatex` please see the MWE later.

For `biblatex` are own styles defined, the one simular to your used `rsc.bst` is `chem-rsc` and best is to use `biber` instead of your used `bibtex`.  The following code does what you need (package `filecontents` is only used to have bib file and tex code together in one compilable code; package `csquotes` is needed for `biblatex` and `\jobname.bib` names the bibfile created with `filecontents`):

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, % <====================================================
  doi=false,     % show no doi in the bibliography <====================
  url=false,
  isbn=false,
  style=chem-rsc % <====================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  % Use bib file created with filecontents
```

The following code builds the link that should be showed. Depending on the given inputs, it shows the doi, if the doi is not available the url, if no url avaiable the isbn etc.:

```
\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}
```

The following code defines, that the *titles* or the *journal names* becomes clickable and shows the given doi, or ...

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}%
  {\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}
```

If you want to change the sign between two or more auhors and the sign after the last author see the following code and change it as you need:

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % \addand
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % \addpunct
```

Because it is not so easy to link the doi to the complete printed bib item I only linked the title or the journal name of your given example.

With the following comlete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{RN8437,
  author = {Garrett, C. G. B. and Brattain, W. H.},
  title = {Physical theory of semiconductor surfaces},
  journal = {Physical Review},
  volume = {99},
  number = {2},
  pages = {376-387},
  ISSN = {0031-899X},
  DOI = {10.1103/PhysRev.99.376},
  year = {1955},
  type = {Journal Article},
}
@book{RN8423,
  author = {Madou, Marc J. and Morrison, S. Roy},
  title = {Chemical sensing with solid state devices},
  publisher = {Academic Press},
  address = {San Diego},
  series = {Chemical sensing with solid state devices},
  ISBN = {978-0-12-464965-1},
  DOI = {10.1016/B978-0-12-464965-1.50006-5},
  url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780124649651500065},
  year = {1989},
  type = {Book},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, % <====================================================
  doi=false,
  url=false,
  isbn=false,
  style=chem-rsc % <====================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}

%\DeclareFieldFormat{default}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}%
  {\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % \addand
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % \addpunct

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   urlcolor=blue,    % color of external links
   linkcolor=black,  % color of toc, list of figs etc.
   citecolor=blue,   % color of links to bibliography
}


\begin{document}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{bibliography}   % bibliography in table of contents

This is rsc \cite{RN8423} reference style \cite{RN8437}. 
%\nocite{*} % to test the complete bib file 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image: resulting bibliography]

Change the delimiters as you need please.