# How to make biblatex/biber aware of \url field in @Phdthesis?

Tags: biblatex, biber, url, hyperlink

I have used instructions on [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn/471334#471334) to hyperlink titles of my references to their respective `url` or `do`i entries. However, it does not work for `@PhdThesis` or `@thesis`, perhaps because `url` is not even an optional field for this document type in BibTeX. However, it is an optional field for `@thesis` in `biblatex`, see p. 12 in http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf. Is there any easy way to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As usual here please add an compilable short tex code showing how you build your bibliography! please do not forget to add two bib entries to your question ...

Comment: What biblatex style do you use? Whether a given field is **used** depends on the style. It should be an easy fix, but we need to know the style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked answer to [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/35864) does indeed not set up links for all entry types. Due to the type-specific formats in  `biblatex`, the

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}%
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}
```

used there does not change the definitions of `inbook` and `thesis` (amongst others). With

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{%
  \usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{#1}}
```

we make sure to link all titles. This is a complete copy of the standard definitions of the `title` field format with `\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}` sprinkled in. See [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864) for more info on the type-specific formatting and how to modify them properly.

In full

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
        }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
    }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}


\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{%
  \usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{elk,
  author      = {Anne Elk},
  year        = {1972},
  title       = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  url         = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  institution = {Monty University},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Anne Elk. “A Theory on Brontosauruses”. PhD thesis. Monty University, 1972." The complete title “A Theory on Brontosauruses” is linked to the URL]

Comment: Thank you, this did it! I thought I had tried adding thesis to `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]` but did not see an effect. Using your code above works.