# Clickable reference to URL

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, tufte, url

Couldn't find this anywhere, so hoping for some assistance here.

I'm doing my master thesis and I as an example I need to reference a lot of information from European Space Agency website.

I'm using overleaf, the tufte book style and a reference in the references.bib could look like this.

```
@misc{sent2radio,
  author = {ESA - Sentinel Online},
  title = {{Sentinel-2} Radoiometric Resolutions},
  year = 2019,
  url = {\url{https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric}},
  urldate = {2019-14-01}
}
```

When I cite that, it is perfectly added to the page and the bottom reference list. The URL is not displayed anywhere, as is common. However, my supervisor has requested that they are able to click the reference in the end of my document, when it turns into a PDF file. So they can check references by going straight to the link. See the image I have attached. Those references I framed in blue, all have individual URL's attached to them and should be directly clickable.

I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example instead of sniplets others cannot test without making a lot of guesses. With bibtex it is important to know which style you are using, again information you do not provide.

Comment: if biblatex is an option for you, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207028/36296

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The code is massive already and contains several additional files. Thats why I did find it a good solution to share it ;) I'll look into the link you provided. Thanks =)

Comment: If you are using `biblatex` then `url = {\url{https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric}},` is wrong, if you are using a BibTeX style it is almost certainly wrong. The `url` field usually contains only the URL in verbatim, no escaping or formatting is applied and no `\url` wrapper is needed. Try `url = {https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric},` instead.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471424/35864

Answer (score 2):

I found a sort of different solution to this. Since the tufte book style has a very large definition file over ruling everything, it can be tedious to move around its code if you are as inexperienced as I in this. However by doing this little trick as shown below, I can make the title clickable - even if it is a bit messy. Its a win, I'll take it.

```
@misc{sent2radio,
  author = {ESA - Sentinel Online},
  title = {\href{https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric}{Sentinel-2 Radiometric Resolutions}},
  year = 2019,
  url = {\url{https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric}},
  urldate = {2019-14-01}
}
```

It completely ignores the url line. But by adding a href to the title. That part is now a clicky!