# How to hide the url of an online bibliographic entry?

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,sorting=ynt,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true,sortcites=true,language=british,doi=false,url=false,backref=true]{biblatex}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

\cite{bop_22}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And a `References.bib` file with an entry like this:

```
@online{bop_22,
    title = {Inmate Statistics},
    author = {{Federal Boreau of Prisons}},
    year = {2022},
    url = {https://www.bop.gov/about/statistics/statistics_inmate_offenses.jsp}
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

I want the title (Inmate Statistics) to be clickable while keeping the ugly and long url totally out of sight, but I can't achieve it. Can you please help me achieve that?

Comment: Literally just the title or is the whole reference clickable acceptable?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. And yes: literally just the title. Actually, my true (not-MWE) document already achieves the title as clickable only, so the issue is to hide the url (something I have achieved with all entry types except the online one, for some reason). However, I thought I would mention the title issue because any solution that breaks it won't be a solution.

Comment: Fair enough :) I have in my template documents a means to hyperlink entire entries (bar the `cit. on etc.` page numbers) and then disable the URL's which I always use with a `bibnote` explaining they are clickable (as the color box does not look nice). Hope someone more experienced in these dark arts can answer, best of luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from this question: [biblatex: make title hyperlink to DOIs, URL or ISBN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/133968). The option `[online]` limits this change only to `online` type references.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,sorting=ynt,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true,sortcites=true,language=british,doi=false,url=false,backref=true]{biblatex}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

% reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/133968
\newbibmacro{string+url}[1]{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{#1}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+url}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{}

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}
    
    \cite{bop_22}
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

[image]