How to use BibLaTeX to mimic RevTeX's hyperlinks in bibliography?
RevTeX has a bibliography style in which the DOI's and URL's of an entry are converted to hyperlinks. Notably, however, these hyperlinks do not appear with the DOI or URL as text, but with the other information about the entry as text. Here's an example:

As you can notice, the title of a book, or the journal information of a paper become a hyperlink, where the link is given by the DOI or URL. I would like to mimic that behavior in documents that do not use RevTeX, and hence I'm looking for a solution using biblatex.
How can I configure biblatex to use the DOI as a link with the journal information, or book title, as text for the hyperlink?

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48409/35864 (it always links the title and not the journaltitle, but apart from that it should be what you want).

Maybe, you need to create a new format, to link the fields to their doi or url. Let's call it linked.
\DeclareFieldFormat{linked}{%
    \iffieldundef{doi}%
        {}%
        {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{doi}}%
                and
                not test {\iffieldundef{url}}}%
        {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}%
        {}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{doi}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{url}}}%
        {#1}%
        {}}

I see that you don't want to print these fields, so I think it would be fine to delete them from the doi+eprint+url bibmacro.
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    % \iftoggle{bbx:doi}%
    %     {\printfield{doi}}%
    %     {}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}%
        {\usebibmacro{eprint}}%
        {}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    % \iftoggle{bbx:url}%
        % {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}%
        {}}

Now, you are ready to set this format. I think it's enought to customise the journal+issuetitle and the maintitle+booktitle macros, to let them printed with this format.
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \printtext[linked]{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}}%
    \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
    \printtext[linked]{%
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}%
        {}%
        {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
         \newunit\newblock%
         \iffieldundef{volume}%
            {}%
            {\printfield{volume}%
            \printfield{part}%
            \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}}%
    \newunit}

Here you back a MWEB.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Maybe, you need to create a new format, to link the fields to their doi or url. Let's call it `linked`.

\DeclareFieldFormat{linked}{%
    \iffieldundef{doi}%
        {}%
        {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{doi}}%
                and
                not test {\iffieldundef{url}}}%
        {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}%
        {}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{doi}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{url}}}%
        {#1}%
        {}}

% I see that you don't want to print these fields, so I think it would be fine to delete them from the `doi+eprint+url` bibmacro.

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    % \iftoggle{bbx:doi}%
    %     {\printfield{doi}}%
    %     {}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}%
        {\usebibmacro{eprint}}%
        {}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    % \iftoggle{bbx:url}%
        % {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}%
        {}}

% Now, you are ready to set this format. I think it's enought to customise the `journal+issuetitle` and the `maintitle+booktitle` macros, to let them printed with this format.

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \printtext[linked]{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}}%
    \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
    \printtext[linked]{%
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}%
        {}%
        {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
         \newunit\newblock%
         \iffieldundef{volume}%
            {}%
            {\printfield{volume}%
            \printfield{part}%
            \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}}%
    \newunit}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{baez/article} hasn't got \texttt{doi} and \texttt{url}. \cite{kastenholz} yes, instead.

\printbibliography
\end{document}

That's the output of mine MWEB.

Just play with it to improve the code according to your preferences or rules.
